# How to use Fluid Assertions .ShouldBeNull()

Tags: c#, tdd, nullreferenceexception, fluent-assertions

I am trying to use the Fluent Assertions ShouldBeNull() extension method to assert that my instance is indeed null.

```
Result.ShouldBeNull();
```

Clearly, this throws an exception because I cannot call the extension on a null instance.

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

How do I use Fluent Assertions properly to make this assertion?

Comment: Have you **actually tried it**?

Comment: Ok, my bad. Another object was null. Still feels rather unnatural, but nothing to do with FluentAssertions I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extension methods *can* be called on objects that are `null`.

See for example http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/01/c-30-extension.html

Think of extension methods not as instance methods, but static methods that take the object (`Result` in your case) as a first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you actually used FluentAssertions, because then your call should have looked like:

```
Result.Should().BeNull()
```

So with the dot .

Answer (score -1):

Result needs to be nullable

`result?.Should().BeNull();`

Even if you're checking for null, you're still trying to do an operation on a null value.